# MySQL - replace multiple values in SELECT

Tags: mysql, str-replace

I create my code in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18aed1

I have 2 tables:

[image]

I need replace multiple groups in users table with name_group like this:
[image]

my code is:

```
SELECT
      name,
      (SELECT name_group FROM groups WHERE id IN (REPLACE(REPLACE(groups ,'{','') , '}',''))) AS groups
FROM `users`
```

Demo: [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18aed1/4)

Thank you

Comment: Honestly, either normalize your structure or just do it in the UI layer

Comment: Please don't store multiple values in one column. That is a real pain like in your case. You should really change your DB structure.